# Best Point Cloud alignment algorithm

Tags: python, alignment, registration, point-clouds, open3d

Please, I have several point clouds (ex. Image 1 et 2) [Images 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkyMK.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjqPy.png) of an object taken by a single stereo camera, and I want to align them.  In these point clouds (PCDs), from their RGB and depth images, I've been able to detect only the regions that interest me (images 3, 4, 5 and 6)[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTet6.png) [Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkTgj.png) [Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPKdO.png) [Image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRchr.png). So for each PCD, I have its RGB and depth image, and a PCD of the regions I'm interested in that contain no noise. My goal is to align all my 10 PCDs to create a complete PCD of the object.

I've tested open3D's various ICP methods (Point-to-point ICP, Point-to-plane ICP, Colored point cloud registration ...) but they don't work for all PCDs, I've tested them on the PCDs of regions of interest and the PCDs of their centers but it only works on a few and not all.

I'd be very grateful if you have any ideas. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried global registration algorithms?